# Trying to add Primary Key to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, key, call, auto-increment

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD PRIMARY KEY `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

It keeps giving me errors about the syntax on adding a primary key.  What will make it go through?

Also, I am trying to add the new column `id` to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `$table` 
  ADD `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary question has been solved, however one very important point. Avoid using `$variable` inside your SQL queries. Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER TABLE `$table`
    ADD `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Also see [the MySQL documentation on ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: guess I forgot to mention that I am trying to add the column to the table.